# Gson not working after packaging msi - Desktop compose

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, gson, compose-desktop

I'm having a little trouble working on a small project in Desktop Compose.
I have the 3 functions below:

```kotlin
package utilities

import com.google.gson.Gson
import serializables.Settings
import java.io.File

fun CheckSettingsFile () {
   if (!File("settings.json").exists()) {
       File("settings.json").createNewFile()
       with(File("settings.json")) {
           val settings = Settings("192.168.1.254","3344")
           val gson = Gson()
           gson.newBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
           val toWrite = gson.toJson(settings)
           this.writeText(toWrite)
       }
   }
}

fun SaveSettings (s : Settings) {
    val gson = Gson()
    gson.newBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
    val serialized = gson.toJson(s)
    try {
        with(File("settings.json")) {
            this.writeText(serialized)
        }
    } catch (err :Exception) {
        println(err.message)
    }
}

fun LoadSettings () : Settings {
    val gson = Gson()
    return  gson.fromJson(File("settings.json").readText(), Settings::class.java)
}
```

While running from IntelliJ IDEA the code works perfectly, but after packaging as msi or exe for Windows I stumble in this error:

`Unable to create instance of class serializables.Settings. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a no-args constructor may fix this problem.`

I haven't tried to solve it like the error message suggests because I'd like to understand what causes the error in the first place.

Here's the `gradle.settings.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")

}

group = "com.eticket"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)

}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb, TargetFormat.Exe)
            packageName = "eTicket"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
            windows {
                shortcut = true
                iconFile.set(project.file("stamp-icon.ico"))
                console = false
                menu = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who feels to share a hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your `Settings` class does not have a no-args constructor, so you are currently implicitly relying on `sun.misc.Unsafe` which is used by Gson to create an instance of this class, see [`GsonBuilder.disableJdkUnsafe()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableJdkUnsafe()) for more details.

The class `sun.misc.Unsafe` is part of the module `jdk.unsupported`, so you can probably solve this by adding the following to your Gradle settings:

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        ...
        nativeDistributions {
            ...
            modules("jdk.unsupported")
        }
    }
}
```

(based on [this comment](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2310#issuecomment-1245814853))

However, note that Gson does not fully support Kotlin (see for example [this issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1657)), so it might be better to switch to a library with explicit Kotlin support, such as Moshi, Jackson or kotlinx-serialization.

Comment: That's exactly what I did: switching to kotlinx.serialization instantly solved the issue. Still, I was curious about why Gson was not working, so thanks for explaining me!